# How to print pattern with an increasing of multiples of 10 in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

### Can anybody please help me to print this pattern...using pow function in php...

```
5

5 50

5 50 500

5 50 500 5000
```

Comment: Using `pow` function or _multiplication_?

Comment: Try posting some code that shows what you've tried so far. Otherwise, it looks like you're just asking for an answer to a homework question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want some implementation of HTML to create the line breaks.

```
<?php
$my_num = 5;
$num_array = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $num_array[] = $my_num * pow(10, $i);
    foreach($num_array as $num) {
        echo "$num ";
    }

    echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank You Mr. Tim Kennell...